# Compile pattern quote inside quote

Tags: java, regex

So I need to compile a pattern that includes a set of `" "` inside it . It won't do the job any other pattern Using this pattern compare.

```
Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("<div class="thumb"><a href=(.*?)-t1");
```

I am reading about it and you need to do something like `"\stuff\"` but I just can't work it in the pattern above. Any help?

Comment: Don't vote to close, give him some time to finish the question.

Comment: I must say I'm actually surprised this question hasn't suffered a downvote bombardment. People must be feeling more civil this morning.

Comment: connection problem guys :( tnx for patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) your quotes:

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"thumb\"><a href=(.*?)-t1");
```

Also, regex against HTML is usually considered to be bad practice.

Comment: I'd say for a limitied use like this, regex is fine.

Comment: Using regex against HTML is only really bad if you're trying to match HTML hierarchies with regex, because that requires recursive matching.

Comment: well for my case Works perfect . Tnx everyone and I apologize for the connection problems ... cheers :)